# Checking for whitespace in a String, keeps throwing a StackOverflowError

Tags: java, regex

So I'm trying to check if a string has any whitespace and return a boolean with the result.

I've tried a couple of regex and I've tried a clunky char comparison but anything I try keeps throwing a StackOverflowError at the first line of setUsername()

Can anyone point out to me what I'm doing wrong here?

```
public void setUsername(String username) {
        if (!this.hasSpaces(username) && username.length() >= 10)
            this.setUsername(username);
        else
            this.setUsername("DefaultStaff");
    }

    public boolean hasSpaces(String str) {
//      Pattern p = Pattern.compile("[\\W]");
//      Matcher m = p.matcher(str);
//      return m.matches();
        char[] tmp = str.toCharArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++)
            if (tmp[i] == ' ')
                return true;
        return false;
    }
```

Comment: `setUsername("ThisIsALongUserNameWithoutSpaces")`, will call `hasSpaces()`, which returns `false`. and `username` is longer than 10 characters, so the method **calls itself with the same argument**, which means it will call `hasSpaces()`, which returns `false`. and `username` is longer than 10 characters, so the method calls itself with the same argument, which means it will call `hasSpaces()`, which returns `false`. and `username` is longer than 10 characters, so the method calls itself with the same argument, which means ... ***StackOverflowError***.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You call `setUsername` in both branches of the if-statement in `setUsername`. That's your infinite recursion.

Instead of calling `setUsername`, you might want to set the field manually, like so:

```
public void setUsername(String username) {
    if (!this.hasSpaces(username) && username.length() >= 10)
        this.username = username;
    else
        this.username = "DefaultStaff";
}
```

Comment: Yep, that'd do it. They're in separate classes so I didn't catch it at first. Thanks mate.

Comment: @Ratu If you ever get a `StackOverflowError`, look at the stack trace for the repeating pattern; there's your loop.